# Получить только html код страницы

Tags: puppeteer

Я использую **puppeteer** для получения html кода страницы сайта.

```
//отключил JS
await browser_page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

await browser_page.goto('https://site.com');
let html_content = await browser_page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);
```

Но часто приходится долго ждать загрузку страницы.
Можно ли как-то получать только html код? минуя "отрисовку" самой страницы?

Но мне очень важно чтобы сайт не посчитал меня за бота, сейчас я использую `puppeteer-extra`, `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth`, `puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker` + рандомные юзер-агенты.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, всё проще:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  const response = await page.goto('https://example.org/', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

  console.log(await response.text());
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```